# Some UTF-8 characters break my ansi-term. How to fix it?

Tags: ansi-term, utf-8

I've got a script that generates some output. Some parts of the output are cyrillic letters, and they cause my `ansi-term` to break - I guess they are treated as control characters(they are displayed like `\320\272`, and this makes me restart the ansi-term hoping it won't happen again(that I skip this part of output). However, this isn't a fix, but a hack.

How can I make these characters appear correctly/not break my con

Comment: Is it *all* cyrillic output, or just *some* that are broken into control characters? If the latter, this could be [Emacs Bug#25288](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25288).

Answer (score 2):

The `\370\272` is Emacs trying to show the character using octal escapes. See the Emacs manual, node [Text Display](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Display.html), and see the Elisp manual, node [Usual Display](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Usual-Display.html).

You can set variable `ctl-arrow` to `t` to see the characters displayed otherwise, using face `escape-glyph`.  But if your font does not enable showing those characters as you expect (Cyrillic) then, well, it can't show them that way. In that case, try a different font.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not really care for these to show up(although that would be nice), the thing I care the most is that they don't break my console. However, I'm using ssh->emacs in console->ansi term, and it looks like my options of changing font are limited. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry. I hope someone else will be able to offer some more help here.